# transparent sprite with event mouseover

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, graphics

I have a actionscript "Sprite" class which load a transparent png.
When i set a "mouseover" event over the Script, it is throw when the mouse goes over the "square" containing the transparent png.

I would like a glow effect to be displayed on mouseover, but only when the mouse is on the displayable part of my transparent .png.

How can i do to throw the event only when the mouse is not over the transparent part of the png? Do i have to check by myself in the mouseover handler then do what i have to do?

Thank you ...

Comment: [InteractivePNG](http://blog.mosessupposes.com/?p=40)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead mouseover you will try enterFrame/mouseMove events and each time check hitTestPoint (with shapeFlag = true) for this Sprite ?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29